# Can I develop an IOS\Android app which can send Facebook notifications (inside FB) to user's friends with customized text?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I hope you are well.

I am developing an App for IOS and Android that will only be logged via Facebook. The info I will retrieve from each user is (1) name (2) photo and (3) friends list. The app will work in a way that each user can send a notification/message/alert to his/her FB friends (with a list inside the app).

I wanted to know if it is possible to program a personalized text that goes in the notification. For example, "john reccomends marvel", where john is the person who sent the notification and marvel is a link to marvel's FB page. Do you know if it is possible to do this?

If not, do you happen to know any other way I can communicate with the user's friend? Maybe via e-mail? Do I have access to user's friends mails?

I appreciate the help in advance.
Cheers,
Luiz henrique